# How do I make two separate calls to an Imagepicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, imagepicker

I want users to be able to upload two separate images to two different parts of the same view.

I'm able to get the first image to show correctly at the top. But whenever the user adds the second image, the image at the top is updated again instead of the image at the bottom.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOi90.png)

Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated!

**ImagePicker**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {

    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    let parent: ImagePicker

    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            parent.image = uiImage
        }

        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var firstImage: Image? = Image("PlaceholderImage")
    @State private var secondImage: Image? = Image("PlaceholderImage")
    @State private var inputImage1: UIImage?
    @State private var inputImage2: UIImage?
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false

    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                    Form {
                        Section(header: Text("First Image")){
                            firstImage!
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
                                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                                .onTapGesture { self.showingImagePicker = true }
                                .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage1) {
                                    ImagePicker(image: self.$inputImage1)
                                }
                        }
                        Section(header: Text("Second Image")){
                            secondImage!
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
                                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                                .onTapGesture { self.showingImagePicker = true }
                                .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage2) {
                                    ImagePicker(image: self.$inputImage2)
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    
    func loadImage1() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage1 else { return }
        firstImage = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
    }
    
    func loadImage2() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage2 else { return }
        secondImage = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is using `sheet(isPresented:)` which can be problematic on iOS 14 because it loads the sheet content of the first render of it (in your case, the `ImagePicker` for the first image) and then doesn't update as one might expect (see [SwiftUI @State and .sheet() ios13 vs ios14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946914/swiftui-state-and-sheet-ios13-vs-ios14) for example).

The solution is to use `sheet(item:)`. In your case, this also involved some other refactoring to get things to work as expected. Here's what I came up with:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var inputImage1: UIImage?
    @State private var inputImage2: UIImage?
    @State private var activeImagePicker : ImagePickerIdentifier? = nil
    
    enum ImagePickerIdentifier : String, Identifiable {
        case picker1, picker2
        
        var id : String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
    
    var image1 : Image {
        if let inputImage1 = inputImage1 {
            return Image(uiImage: inputImage1)
        } else {
            return Image("Placeholder")
        }
    }
    
    var image2 : Image {
        if let inputImage2 = inputImage2 {
            return Image(uiImage: inputImage2)
        } else {
            return Image("Placeholder")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("First Image")){
                    image1
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture { self.activeImagePicker = .picker1 }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Second Image")) {
                    image2
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 200, alignment: .center)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture { self.activeImagePicker = .picker2 }
                }
                
            }
            .sheet(item: $activeImagePicker) { picker in
                switch picker {
                case .picker1:
                    ImagePicker(image: $inputImage1)
                case .picker2:
                    ImagePicker(image: $inputImage2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I got rid of your `onDismiss` function, because it was unnecessary here, but if you *did* need it for your real implementation, I'd suggest using `onDisappear` on the individual `ImagePicker`s, which will let you differentiate which one is being dismissed.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks so much for the quick help!

Comment: @Buckiteer Hello, could you help me? I have the same topic within a foreach, can you give me an idea to store the image in the correct position?  [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607164/imagepicker-in-array)