# ImagePicker in array

Tags: swiftui, imagepicker

I am trying to make a dynamic image selection with the help of an array, but the problem I have is that I select the first position and the photo loads in the first position, but if I select another position, the image always loads in the first position.

I am occupying a single .sheet within the foreach, it is worth mentioning that what I want to achieve is a number of images, not a fixed size

code:

```
import SwiftUI


struct Research {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var date: String
    var aux: Int
    var imagen1: UIImage
    var imagen2: UIImage
    var imagen3: UIImage
    var imagen4: UIImage
    var imagen5: UIImage
    var imagen6: UIImage
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dataResearch : [Research] = []
    @State var aux: Int = 0
    @State var showPicker: Bool = false //  I imagine that this variable must be unique per element
    @State var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach($dataResearch, id: \.aux) { $i in
                VStack{
                    Image(uiImage:  i.imagen1)
                      .resizable()
                      .scaledToFill()
                      .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                      .onTapGesture(){
                          showPicker = true
                      }
                    Image(uiImage:  i.imagen2)
                      .resizable()
                      .scaledToFill()
                      .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                      .onTapGesture(){
                          showPicker = true
                      }
                      
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showPicker) {
                    ImagePicker(sourceType: sourceType, selectedImage: $i.imagen1)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            getRequest()
        }
    }
    
    
    func getRequest(){
        let image1: UIImage =  UIImage(named: "default_image")!
        let image2: UIImage  =  UIImage(named: "default_image")!
        let image3: UIImage  =  UIImage(named: "default_image")!
        let image4: UIImage  =  UIImage(named: "default_image")!
        let image5: UIImage  =  UIImage(named: "default_image")!
        let image6: UIImage  =  UIImage(named: "default_image")!
       
        let row = Research(id: 0, name: "", date: "", aux: aux, imagen1: image1, imagen2: image2, imagen3: image3, imagen4: image4, imagen5: image5, imagen6: image6)
         dataResearch.append(row)
        
        aux = aux + 1
    }
    
}
```

IMAGE PICKER

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    
    //@Binding var selectedImage: SelectImage
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
            print("aqui vemos-- ", parent)
            print("aqui vemos-- ", parent.selectedImage)
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = image
                //var row1 = SelectImage(id: 0, uiImage: image ,name:"")
                //parent.selectedImage.uiImage = image
            }
            
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without a [mre], it's not possible to effectively debug and help with this.

Comment: @jnpdx Update my code, I hope to be successful this time

Comment: Still not enough for a reproducible example (you didn't include `ImagePicker`) but I was able to piece it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a little bit complicated because of the structure of `Research` and the fact that it has so many image fields (that aren't in an array). I'd suggest that it's possible that your model could use a refactor, but since I don't have any information about what the end goal is, I don't know exactly what that would involve yet.

With your current code, you can set a selected item and then set an additional variable that determines which `imagen(X)` property it should be bound to:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dataResearch : [Research] = []
    @State private var aux: Int = 0
    @State private var pickerItem : Binding<Research>? // the item from ForEach
    
    private enum SelectedImage {
        case imagen1, imagen2
    }
    
    @State private var selectedImage : SelectedImage? //which image gets selected 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach($dataResearch, id: \.aux) { $i in
                VStack{
                    Image(uiImage:  i.imagen1)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .onTapGesture(){
                            pickerItem = $i
                            selectedImage = .imagen1
                        }
                    Image(uiImage:  i.imagen2)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .onTapGesture(){
                            pickerItem = $i
                            selectedImage = .imagen2
                        }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $pickerItem) { [selectedImage] item in
                VStack {
                    if let selectedImage = selectedImage {
                        switch selectedImage {
                        case .imagen1:
                            ImagePicker(selectedImage: item.imagen1)
                        case .imagen2:
                            ImagePicker(selectedImage: item.imagen2)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
            getRequest()
        }
    }
    
    
    func getRequest(){
        let image1: UIImage =  UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!
        let image2: UIImage  =   UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!
        let image3: UIImage  =   UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!
        let image4: UIImage  =   UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!
        let image5: UIImage  =   UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!
        let image6: UIImage  =   UIImage(systemName: "pencil")!
        
        let row = Research(id: 0, name: "", date: "", aux: aux, imagen1: image1, imagen2: image2, imagen3: image3, imagen4: image4, imagen5: image5, imagen6: image6)
        dataResearch.append(row)
        
        aux = aux + 1
    }
}
```