# SwiftUI Issue with State with Toggle/Sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

### Intro

Takes this simple view as an example.

```
@State private var isOn: Bool = false
@State private var isPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(content: {
        Button("Present", action: { isPresented = true })
        
        Toggle("Lorem Ipsum", isOn: $isOn)
    })
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            Text(String(isOn))
                .onAppear(perform: { print("> \(isOn)") })
        })
}
```

A simple `VStack` displays a `Button` that presents a `Sheet`, and a `Toggle` that modifies a local property. `VStack` has a `Sheet` modifier applied to it, that simply displays property modified by the `Toggle`.

Sounds simple, but there are issues in certain conditions.

### Different App Runs

App Run 1 (No Bug):

1. Don't press `Toggle` (set to false)
2. Open `Sheet`
3. `Text` shows "false" and console logs "false"

App Run 2 (Bug):

1. Press `Toggle` (true)
2. Open `Sheet`
3. `Text` shows "false" and console logs "true"

App Run 3 (No Bug):

1. Press `Toggle` (true)
2. Open `Sheet`
3. Close `Sheet`
4. Press `Toggle` (false)
5. Press `Toggle` (true)
6. Open `Sheet`
7. `Text` shows "true" and console logs "true"

In the second run, `Text` in `Sheet` displays "false", while console logs "true". But closing the sheet and re-toggling the `Toggle` fixes the issue.

Also, console logs the following warning:

`invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.`

### Weird Fix

Adding same `Text` inside the `VStack` as well seems to fix the issue.

```
@State private var isOn: Bool = false
@State private var isPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(content: {
        Button("Present", action: { isPresented = true })
        
        Toggle("Lorem Ipsum", isOn: $isOn)
        
        Text(String(isOn)) // <--
    })
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            Text(String(isOn))
                .onAppear(perform: { print("> \(isOn)") })
        })
}
```

Problem can also be fixed by using `onChange` modifier.

```
@State private var isOn: Bool = false
@State private var isPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(content: {
        Button("Present", action: { isPresented = true })
        
        Toggle("Lorem Ipsum", isOn: $isOn)
    })
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            Text(String(isOn))
                .onAppear(perform: { print("> \(isOn)") })
        })
        .onChange(of: isOn, perform: { _ in }) // <--
}
```

### Other UI Components

I have two custom made `Toggle` and `BottomSheet` components that are build in SwiftUI from scratch. I have also used them in the test.

Using native `Toggle` with my `BottomSheet` causes problem.

Using my `Toggle` with native `Sheet` DOESN'T cause problem.

Using my `Toggle` with my `Sheet` DOESN'T cause problem.

Swapping out native `Toggle` with native `Button` also causes the same issue:

```
@State private var isOn: Bool = false
@State private var isPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(content: {
        Button("Present", action: { isPresented = true })
        
        Button("Toggle", action: { isOn.toggle() }) // <--
    })
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            Text(String(isOn))
                .onAppear(perform: { print("> \(isOn)") })
        })
}
```

### Update

As suggested in the comments, using `Sheet` `init` with `Binding` item seems so solve the issue:

```
private struct Sheet: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = .init()
    let isOn: Bool
}

@State private var presentedSheet: Sheet?
@State private var isOn: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(content: {
        Button("Present", action: { presentedSheet = .init(isOn: isOn) })

        Toggle("Lorem Ipsum", isOn: $isOn)
    })
        .padding()
        .sheet(item: $presentedSheet, content: { sheet in
            Text(String(sheet.isOn))
        })
}
```

However, as other older threads suggested, this may be a bug in SwiftUI, introduced in `2.0`.

Another way of fixing the issue that doesn't require creating a new object and doing additional bookkeeping is just leaving an empty `onChange` modifier: `.onChange(of: isOn, perform: { _ in })`.

```
extension View {
    func bindToModalContext<V>(
        _ value: V
    ) -> some View
        where V : Equatable
    {
        self
            .onChange(of: value, perform: { _ in })
    }
}
```

Other threads:

[SwiftUI @State and .sheet() ios13 vs ios14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946914/swiftui-state-and-sheet-ios13-vs-ios14)

https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/l744cb/running_into_state_issues_using_sheets/

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661777

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659660

Comment: You are using the wrong `.sheet()` initializer for this. You want `sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`. It allows you to establish a `Binding` connection between the view and the sheet.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to solve the issue. I have edited the post, however this is definitely a bug in SwiftUI. Otherwise, why would writing an empty `onChange` modifier fix the problem? Unlike what you wrote, `onChange` modifier is separate and doesn't establish any back-forth connection between view and `Sheet `, but still seems to work just as fine.

Comment: This is actually not a bug. The `isPresented` initializer doesn't capture the value; `item` does.

Comment: Okay. I got the impression that it was a bug since threads form 1-2 years ago mentioned that this "issue" was introduced with iOS 14.0.

Answer (score 3):

The sample code demonstrating the issue can be simplified to this:

```
struct SheetTestView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") {
            isPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Text(isPresented.description)
        }
    }
}
```

The thing you have to understand first is part of SwiftUI's magic is dependency tracking. Where `body` is only called if it actually uses a var that changes. Unfortunately that behavior does not extend to the code within blocks passed to view modifiers like sheet. So in the code above, SwiftUI is asking itself does any of the Views inside body display the value of `isPresented`? And that answer is no, so when the value of `isPresented` is changed, it does not need to call `body` and it doesn't.

So when `body` is called the first time, the block that is created for the sheet is using the original value of `isPresented` which is `false`. When the `Button` is pressed and `isPresented` is set to `true`, the block is called immediately and thus it still is using the value `false`.

Now you understand what is happening, a workaround is to make `body` actually use the value of `isPresented`, e.g.

```
struct SheetTestView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present (isPresented: \(isPresented))") { // now body has a dependency on it
            isPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Text(isPresented.description)
        }
    }
}
```

Now SwiftUI, does detect a dependency for body on the value of `isPresented` so the behaviour is now different. When the `Button` is pressed, instead of the sheet block being called immediately, actual body is called first, and thus a new sheet block is created and this one now uses the new value of `isPresented` which is true and the problem is fixed.

This workaround may be undesirable, so a way to ensure the problem doesn't happen is to use a feature of Swift called a capture list, this makes a dependency on the value of `isPresented` without actually having to display it, e.g.

```
struct SheetTestView: View {
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present (isPresented: \(isPresented))") {
            isPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) { [isPresented] in // capture list
            Text(isPresented.description)
        }
    }
}
```

This trick does make `body` depend on `isPresented` in SwiftUI's eyes, so body is called when the `Button` action changes `isPresented` and then a new block is created that is passed to sheet and does have the correct value, problem solved!

Comment: Your workaround is quite elegant. :-)

Comment: Sent a feedback report to Apple: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5605568903380992. Hopefully, they can find a good way to resolve this issue within SwiftUI itself.