# My Swift program is crashing with :Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Tags: swiftui, unwrapping

Line 30 set the value to showFood, and the line 32 print it ,is not null. but the line 49 show variable showFood is nil and get error. I do not know why.

i have try my best ,but i donot why showFood on line 49 is nil .

[image]

code below

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.dynamicTypeSize) private var textSize
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editModel
    @State var food = Food.examples
    @State var shouldShowSheet: Bool = false
    @State var selectedFoodID = Set<Food.ID>()
    @State var selectedFood: Binding<Food>?
    var isEditing: Bool {
        editModel?.wrappedValue == .active
    }

    @State var shouldShowForm: Bool = false
    @State var showFood: Food?
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            List($food, editActions: .all, selection: $selectedFoodID) { $food in
                HStack {
                    Text(food.name)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            showFood = food
                            print(showFood) // showFood here is not null
                        }
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $shouldShowSheet, content: {
            let foo = showFood! // showFood is null.  and get error here. i donot why 

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.sheet(item` instead of `.sheet(isPresented`

Comment: You should use `.sheet(item: $showFood ...` instead to avoid this issue. And never force unwrap, use `guard` or `if let` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI @State and .sheet() ios13 vs ios14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946914/swiftui-state-and-sheet-ios13-vs-ios14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you forgot to call the `showFood` getter somewhere in `body` which is how SwiftUI decides if `body` needs to be called when a state is set. This usually means you've declared the wrong kind of `@State`. As a quick fix you can workaround the problem by faking a read like:

```
sheet(isPresented: $shouldShowSheet) { [showFood] {
```

But it would be best if you used a different sheet modifier, e.g.

```
.sheet(item: $showFood) {
```

Now a new sheet will be recreated when showFood changes and it will have the latest value and not crash.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue before, and it seems like SwiftUI couldn't determine a @State object that doesn't conform to `Equatable` in such this circumstance. You can either change to `.sheet(item:)` or make `Food` fully conform to `Equatable` to fix this.

```swift
struct Food: Identifiable, Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: Food, rhs: Food) -> Bool {
    ...
  }
}
```